In Python colorsys is there a way to convert hlsa_to_rgb?
I am looking at colors pulled from the background color cells of an excel spreadsheet using Python.
Oddly, what I pull from the fill color in RGB does not match what I am getting in the excel spreadsheet in python for the color.
It leads me to believe that excel is using hlsa as it's storage format; because when I pull it from the sheet using the API it comes back as eight hex-digits and not six as expected.
Instead of being RGB (RRGGBB) it's RRGGBBAA (wrong I think) or maybe more likely HHLLSSAA or something along those lines.
I've had a hard time finding information about color standards for hex colors.
It used to be that everything was RRGGBB, but it seems like things have gotten more complicated in the years since I was a web developer.
I am trying to use the webcolors library to fuzzily identify colors with a name; but the webcolors library seems to use RGB/RRGGBB and so the colors are mis-identified when I pull them from the sheet.
I found the native colorsys library of python, but I don't see that it has a hlsa_to_rgb method, only a hls_to_rgb method.
I also had a crazy idea that I could save my excel spreadsheet in an older format and the problem would just disappear; but it turns out that openpyxl doesn't read those sorts of formats.

It's probably first hex is the Alpha, then the next 3 are the RGB.

How about making a spreadsheet and saving one cell as red, one as lime-green and one as blue and a few with partial transparency and seeing what you get?

@MarkSetchell There's nothing behind the cells; this isn't Visio or Powerpoint; it's Excel; why do the colors need transparency?  Is it because you can copy and paste between these programs?  That's the only reason I can think of.  Okay, I'lk give it a try.
